# Change color of Navigation drawer three Lines icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How can I change color of navigation drawer menu icon(three horizontal lines) or if I can change that image will also be helpful

Comment: use these links references .You can use colors.xml to define custom colors [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)

Comment: replace image ic_drawer.png with icon on this link: http://www.icons4android.com/icon/1837

Comment: I don't have any ic_drawer.png in my project

Comment: Are you using Toolbar from the design support library?

Comment: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout